# ArrayList remove and clear functions

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of objects that each of which has a reference to a bitmap.

if I use ArrayList.remove or ArrayList.clear, to remove an object or all of them respectively,

do I need to set the reference to the bitmap to null first or does the remove/clear does it?

I ask this for memory concern, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to clear memory of a bitmap object you should use it recycle method.

```
bitmap.recycle()
```

Thats how the memory associated with the bitmap is cleared. As additional phone memory is used to store information of the bitmap pixel values which will be cleard using the recycle function.

Comment: the problem is there may be other references to the same bitmap, so I can't use bitmap.recycle();

Comment: ok then all you need to do is clear or remove to just remove the reference.